# How to add list of data to database from ASP.NET (Task<IHttpActionResult> list)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, http-post, dto

Hi there I very new to ASP.NET I want to post a list of data from java script using post and pass the data to controller in order to save the data in database. ***Currently I'm stuck at the controller part can anyone guide on the controller part***. I will provide my code that I develop till now

JAVASCRIPT PART

```
function UpdateData() {

    var things = [
        { ID: 1, QUANTITY: 1, CODE: 1, DESCRIPTION: 'ONE'},
        { ID: 2, QUANTITY: 2, CODE: 2, DESCRIPTION: 'ONE'},
        { ID: 3, QUANTITY: 3, CODE: 3, DESCRIPTION: 'THREE'}
    ];      

    things = JSON.stringify({ 'things': things });

    return ajaxPromise({
        url: UpdateUrl,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: things
    }).then(function (result) {

    }, function (e) {
        console.error(e);
        alert(e.responseText);
      
    });
}
```

DTO

```
public class DataDTO
{
    public int ID{ get; set; }

    public int QUANTITY{ get; set;}

    public int CODE{ get; set; }

    public string DESCRIPTION{ get; set; }

}
```

CONTROLLER PART

```
[HttpPost] 

public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateData(List<DataDTO> data){

 var results = new List<DataDTO>();
       
 foreach (var item in results)
        {
            var newRecords = new newData();
            newRecords.ID= item.ID;
            newRecords.QUANTITY= item.QUANTITY;
            newRecords.CODE= item.CODE;               
            newRecords.DESCRIPTION= item.DESCRIPTION;
            
            db.newData.Add(newRecords);
        }           

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok("Save successfully");  }
```

Comment: You seem to loop an empty List in your Controller `UpdateData(List<DataDTO> data)`. The parameter `data` should be looped by the `foreach`. instead of `results`.

Comment: Hi now I'm able to pass the data from javascript to my controller and able to go through the for each function but the problem now whenever it runs await db.SaveChangesAsync(); or db.SaveChanges(); in for each loop it keep throwing me exception error

Answer (score 0):

As whereas You named your data 'things' in the javascript part so You should call it 'things' in the controller part and then run foreach on 'things'.

```
[HttpPost] 

public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateData(List<DataDTO> things){
   
foreach (var item in things)
    {
        var newRecords = new newData();
        newRecords.ID= item.ID;
        newRecords.QUANTITY= item.QUANTITY;
        newRecords.CODE= item.CODE;               
        newRecords.DESCRIPTION= item.DESCRIPTION;
        
        db.newData.Add(newRecords);
    }           

    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return JavaScript("alert('It Was Done OK')");
    }
```

Comment: Hi @Mahdi now I'm able to pass the data from javascript to my controller and able to go through the for each function but the problem now whenever it runs await db.SaveChangesAsync(); or db.SaveChanges(); in for each loop it keep throwing me exception error

Comment: probably it's because of converting DTO to Entity please attach your Entity Too. To I check it

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Mahdi I have almost the same kind of situation but whenever I pass the things data the
in

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateData(List<DataDTO> things){
```

the data is passing as null I don't knw why the data unable to pass to controller but I have been try using **JObject Model** now I able to see the data but I don't know how to use **JObject Model** to pass the list of data to add in database

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think You should change this code

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UpdateData(List<DataDTO> things){
```

to this code

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateData(IEnumerable<DataDTO> things)
```

and please be sure that you are running your foreach on the 'things', I think you are using some empty list in the foreach loop please check your foreach to be like this:

```
foreach (var item in things)
```